# Can every CW complex be presented as a countable collection of integer valued matrices?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I had this epiphany today and i'd really like to verify it, since i'm starting to seriously doubt myself...

Let $X$ be a connected CW complex. It can be written as a colimit of it's sequence skeletons:

$$\cdots \to X^{n-1} \xrightarrow{j_{n-1}} X^n \xrightarrow{j_n} X^{n+1}  \to \cdots$$

Such that at every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there's a cofiber sequence $\bigvee S^n  \xrightarrow{\phi_n} X^n \xrightarrow{j_n} X^{n+1}$.

For some reason I don't yet understand so well apart from invoking whitehead theorem (and would delight to have a simple explanatioon for) the homotopy type of a CW complex depends only on the homotopy type of the attaching maps. By this reasoning and by the cellular approximation theorem one can modify all the maps such that at every step of the sequence the attaching maps satisfy:

$$\phi_n \in [\bigvee^k S^n, \bigvee^l S^n ] \cong \mathcal{M}_{k,l}(\mathbb Z)$$

Is something wrong here?

If so can it be remedied so that a similar description is stil possible?

If not, this must make the passage to the cellular complex entirely algorithmic. Or am i missing something?

Comment: The reason you only need to remember the homotopy type of the attaching map is that taking homotopy cofibers is a homotopy invariant operation.

Comment: Indeed, the set of homology places from a wedge of spheres to another is considerably more complicated than those matrices!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I meant homotopy classes of maps between spheres of the same dimension which i'm pretty sure are just integer matrices. Of course i was far off since the image could lie in all the lower dimensional cells and things get horribly complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider the homotopy type of a map between a wedge of spheres and the previous stage in the CW decomposition, and there's no way to guarantee that this is another wedge of spheres of the same dimension.

For example, suppose you want to understand complexes built by starting from a wedge of $k$-spheres and attaching an $(n+1)$-cell. Then you need to understand homotopy classes of maps $S^n \to \bigvee S^k$, and these are quite complicated. In addition to needing to understand the homotopy group $\pi_n(S^k)$, you also need to take into account [Whitehead brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_product).

Comment: What a stupid mistake i got skeletons and cells mixed up when using the cellular approximation theorem. Sorry for the trouble. Regarding your comment about the homotopy invariance. Am i correct in translating it as: The whole diagram of the CW complex is cofibrant and so the homotopy colimit coincides with the colimit. The homotopy colimit is by construction invariant under pointwise homotopies so the colimit is invariant as well.